# Denial of service issue in lite-server

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, lite-server

I had installed lite-server today and it is showing that lite-server vulnerable to denial of service . Will it affect my system if i use lite-server further.
Is there any solution to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `lite-server` is meant to be development only server - it should be ok, since you're using it only locally - DoS attack would be only possible locally.

Therefore you should **NEVER USE** it in production environments and use something more appropriate for the job.